# CentOS Logins - Root UI and Single User

Tags: centos

I have 2 questions around creating accounts in CentOS 7.

- How do you create a user that has access to the the Gnome desktop within single user mode?
- How do you permit root login to the Gnome desktop?

Thanks,

Comment: When you say UI are you meaning the GUI.

Comment: yep, that is correct

Comment: first question unclear => close, second question legitimate (?) => leave open. I'll skip (from review)

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Nope - still no good.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answers

1. You don't. (Single user mode is for extreme system maintenance, so only root will have the ability to login. And even then probably not in graphical mode.)
2. You don't. Use `sudo`, or a graphical equivalent, when you need root privileges, and stay safe.